# Can I select the target for my spawn larvae with a hotkey and no mouse clicks?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I have my queens hotkeyed so I can double tap the key, hit V for spawn larvae, then click my hatchery.  However, I would like to get rid of the need for the mouse click.  Can I somehow select the target for my spawn larvae with just a hotkey?  That way I could keep my larvae flowing with less distraction.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this would work, but maybe the backspace key? Maybe if you had your hatcheries in control-groups, you might be able to press that number for the control group?

Comment: This is a little "inside baseball," but you used to be able to cast it on the icon in your control group.  However, this functionality was removed before the end of beta.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't avoid to click, but you can click on the minimap.

If you select all your queens (say in a single control group) and cast spawn larva on the minimap, the closest queen will cast spawn larva on the closest hatchery to where you clicked.

This is another function of smart casting.

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: Set all Queens to one control group. Then press the control group key (say 5), and hit V. Now click on your hatcheries on the minimap and the Queens will each inject on their Hatchery.

Comment: will def try this. thx.

Comment: I wonder if there's a similar trick with Terran mules.

Comment: @ripper234 I'd venture to say there isn't. Spawn Larva is a lot more specific than Mule targeting. It only works on hatcheries, while you can drop a Mule anywhere.

Comment: @Ripper234 mules will spawn where ever you target them, but if you don't target minerals specifically they will not automatically harvest.

Comment: When using the minimap trick, you cannot just click on empty space around the hatchery. You must click on the actual Hatchery on the minimap

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  The way you're doing it is likely the fastest you can hope for.

Comment: See @e-satis's answer. It is faster and more uniformly applies to multiple hatcheries.

Answer (score 0):

I do see this is a very old question. But, here is another, even better, method. If you have all your queens on a single hot key. Then to spawn larve on all your hatcheries all you need to do is hold shift, click V once, then hit your button to cycle through all your bases. The default key for this is backspace. However, I switched that key for me to "tab".

Using this method all you need to click is the hotkey, then keep your mouse centered on the screen and click after each tab. You can do this very quickly between a great number of bases. This is way more simple then clicking the hatcheries on the mini-map as this method takes precision to hit such a small target accurately.

[Youtube video on how its done with using the default backspace key.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4MDb_hzuyo)