# Using Queen and Chrono Boost Effectively

Tags: starcraft-2

So it looks like both the Queen and Chrono Boost come up every 25 seconds and each last 20 seconds, so unless your using them on multiple targets, you need to be checking back on these things every 25 seconds, which is really hard for me to juggle with everything else going on constantly.

Is there a faster way to automatically target the nexus/hive?  It's pretty easy for me to queue up gathering units, because I can just hit 1 and then E, and I don't have to move my screen back to my base or use the mouse.  It just seems silly to me that the mouse needs to be used for this task because the mouse is so much slower.

Also what is the prescribed role of the Queen/Chrono Boost?  Do you always want 1 queen per hive and blasting them every 25 seconds, right?  And is Chrono Boost usually used on the nexus itself except when you need to rush out some troops?

Thanks

Comment: Queens have already been talked about in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/spawn-larva-with-no-mouse-clicks
Perhaps a similar approach works for chrono boost?

Comment: Duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/spawn-larva-with-no-mouse-clicks The same thing could apply to Protoss too?

Comment: @McKay Ya, Javadoc has the same link.  I'm going to try that with Protoss tonight to see if that works too.  You have a few more options with Chrono Boost there, which also brings up the question of Chrono Boost strategy.

Comment: Even if chrono-boost does work, it works on more buildings than just the nexus, so if you have other buildings near it (or are on a large map), you may inadvertently end up casting it on the wrong building.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Yeah, what I do if there are lots of buildings, is then click on the minimap, then left click on the appropriate building on the regular map. A little more annoying, but still pretty fast.

Comment: @Dan: This Team Liquid Forum Post might interest you, eventhough many posters there argue about it's real use: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=150871&currentpage=13#257

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As JavadocMD pointed we have discussed Queen usage [at length](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/spawn-larva-with-no-mouse-clicks).  To help extrapolate on the Queen consider the following: If you have 3 or more Hatcheries, its likely that you're approaching the Control cap.  At this point is it really worth it to produce additional Queens which will not be involved in battle?  The Queen does work as an efficient defensive unit, but Spine/Spore Crawlers can also function in this roll and require no additional Supply.  Additionally, if you have more than 3 Hatcheries, your production is very high, and as those bases become mined out, your income will not be as high.  Thus its often less worthwhile to produce Queens at bases after your first expansion or two.

On the subject of Chrono Boost, I often find it hard to spend efficiently late game but here are a couple things that may help:

- Warpgates can be Chrono Boosted
- Research can be Chrono Boosted
- If you have as many Robo/Starport as Nexus, you can often Chrono Boost them
- If you have more than 50 energy on a Nexus you can spend it on two buildings (instead of having to wait for it to finish off on one).
- After early game, Probe production slows because its usually constrained by the number of expansions you are bootstrapping

For what its worth, I still have the habit of cycling through my Hatcheries every ~25 seconds to guarantee effective usage.  Because of smart cast I can even leave all my queens in one group if necessary.